# Soapui Groovy - No Signature of Method error on ProWsdlTestSuitePanelBuilder.buildDesktopPanel

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm working on a script to automate the running of several TestSuites across multiple projects concurrently in SoapUI 4.5.1:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.testsuite.*;

def properties = new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap();
def currentProject = testRunner.getTestCase().testSuite.getProject();
def workspace = currentProject.getWorkspace();

def otherProject = workspace.getProjectByName('Project 1');
def otherTestSuite = CGReportsProject.getTestSuiteByName('TestSuite 1');

otherTestSuite.run(properties, true);
```

However, I'm also attempting to open the TestSuite Panel for each of the TestSuites that are run by the script to allow visual tracking of the Suites' progress. That's where I run into trouble:

```
ProWsdlTestSuitePanelBuilder.buildDesktopPanel(otherTestSuite);
```

This particular line throws the error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
static com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.testsuite.
ProWsdlTestSuitePanelBuilder.buildDesktopPanel() is
applicable for argument types: 
(com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlTestSuitePro) values:
[com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlTestSuitePro@1d0b2bc6] 
Possible solutions: 
buildDesktopPanel(com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlTestSuitePro),
buildDesktopPanel(com.eviware.soapui.model.ModelItem),
buildDesktopPanel(com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlTestSuite),
buildDesktopPanel(com.eviware.soapui.model.ModelItem),
buildDesktopPanel(com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlTestSuite),
buildDesktopPanel(com.eviware.soapui.model.ModelItem)
error at line: 12
```

Which I take to mean that the instance of the WsdlTestSuitePro I'm throwing at ProWsdlTestSuitePanelBuilder.buildDesktopPanel() isn't being accepted for some reason - but I've no idea why.

At this point, I'm also not sure if the ProWsdlTestSuitePanelBuilder.buildDesktopPanel() is really what I want anyway, but it's the only UI builder that'll take a WsdlTestSuitePro, as that apparently what all my Testsuites are.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this falls under the newbie catagory. I wasn't paying attention to the fact that buildDesktopPanel was static.

However, I managed to work around that and create the final product:

```
// Create a UISupport container for all the panels we'll be showing

def UIDesktop = new com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport();

// Basic environment information

def properties = new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap();
def currentProject = testRunner.getTestCase().testSuite.getProject();
def workspace = currentProject.getWorkspace();

// Get the various Projects we'll be using

def OtherProject = workspace.getProjectByName('Other Project');

// Get the various TestSuites we'll be running

def OtherTestSuite = OtherProject.getTestSuiteByName('Other Test Suite');

// Generate the Panels for the Testsuites

def TestSuitePanel = new com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.testsuite.ProWsdlTestSuiteDesktopPanel(OtherTestSuite);

// Show TestSuite Panels

UIDesktop.showDesktopPanel(TestSuitePanel);

// Run the Testsuites

OtherTestSuite.run(properties, true);
```